# React multi-file uploader component repeatedly uploads files

Tags: reactjs, upload, xmlhttprequest, immer.js

I am creating a file upload component in React using XHR and immerjs.  It show's the files progress as it is uploaded. The user can select multiple files so they upload simultaneously.

Uploading a single file looks to work fine (except that the status should be `uploading` after starting -- not `unprocessed`). The console log looks like this:

```
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file1.png 18% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 36% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 55% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 73% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 91% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 100% unprocessed
onComplete
loadEndEventListener
```

But when you upload two files at once, it looks like the files are getting uploaded over and over again.

Eg if I upload file1.png and file2.png, the console log looks like this:

```
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
starting to upload file2.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file1.png 3% unprocessed
starting to upload file2.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file2.png 5% unprocessed
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file1.png 7% unprocessed
starting to upload file2.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file2.png 10% unprocessed
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file1.png 3% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 11% unprocessed
starting to upload file2.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file2.png 16% unprocessed
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file2.png 5% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 3% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 15% unprocessed
starting to upload file2.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file2.png 10% unprocessed
onProgress file2.png 21% unprocessed
starting to upload file1.png (unprocessed)
onProgress file1.png 7% unprocessed
onProgress file2.png 10% unprocessed
onProgress file1.png 7% unprocessed

...
```

Here is a link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cache-kwtrp?file=/src/App.js

Here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import produce from "immer";

function File({ name, progress }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} {progress}%
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Uploader() {
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState([]);

  function onComplete() {
    console.log("onComplete");
  }

  function loadEndEventListener() {
    console.log("loadEndEventListener");
  }

  function errorEventListener(e) {
    console.log("errorEventListener");
  }

  function abortEventListener(e) {
    console.log("abortEventListener");
  }

  // file: { progress, status, FileBrowserData: { name, size, type } }
  function uploadFile(file) {
    function onProgress(e) {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        const index = files.findIndex(_file => _file.FileBrowserData.name === file.FileBrowserData.name);

        console.log(`onProgress ${file.FileBrowserData.name} ${parseInt(percentComplete)}% ${file.status}`);

        setFiles(
          produce(files, draftFiles => {
            draftFiles[index].progress = percentComplete;
            draftFiles[index].status = "uploading";
          })
        );
      }
    }

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", file.FileBrowserData);

    const oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "https://webhook.site/12e03896-442d-42ee-8e2a-63a7cb05a9b9");

    oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", onProgress);
    oReq.upload.addEventListener("load", onComplete);
    oReq.upload.addEventListener("loadend", loadEndEventListener);
    oReq.upload.addEventListener("error", errorEventListener);
    oReq.upload.addEventListener("abort", abortEventListener);

    oReq.send(fd);
  }

  function uploadUnprocessedFiles() {
    files
      .filter(file => file.status === "unprocessed")
      .forEach(file => {
        console.log(`starting to upload ${file.FileBrowserData.name} (${file.status})`);
        uploadFile(file);
      });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    uploadUnprocessedFiles();
  }, [files]);

  function renderFiles() {
    return files.map(file => (
      <File key={file.FileBrowserData.name} name={file.FileBrowserData.name} progress={file.progress} />
    ));
  }

  function populateFilesInState(fileList) {
    const _fileList = Array.from(fileList).slice(0);

    setFiles(() =>
      _fileList.map(file => ({
        progress: 0,
        status: "unprocessed",
        FileBrowserData: file,
      }))
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>File selector:</h3>
      <input
        type="file"
        multiple={true}
        onChange={e => {
          populateFilesInState(e.target.files);
        }}
      />
      <h3>Files:</h3>
      {renderFiles()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.